# Errno 13 Permission denied : u'processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz'

Tags: amazon-s3

I just use the code "aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset --key AOI_1_Rio/processedData/processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz --request-payer requester processedBuildingLabels.tar.gz" to download the data. But it keeps coming out such error.

Comment: Please include the permissions settings for this file from your AWS console. A permission denied error is exactly that, you do not provide the correct permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your responding. I solve the problem by deleting another version of python on my computer. I am guessing it's because the version confliction